# Issue on adding Class to list

Tags: jquery

Can you please let me know why I am not able to add class to list here:[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/wSt6Q/2/)
and here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $("li").on("click", function () {
        //alert( $( this ).text() );
        $(this).addClass("red");
    });
});
```

Comment: can someone please let me know why this question got -2?! I strongly believe Stackoverflow MUST stop some genius! to behave like this with other people questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add class for link tag not li tag.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $("li a").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //alert( $( this ).text() );
        $(this).addClass("red");
    });
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wSt6Q/5/)

Comment: The specific problem is that the `href` attributes on his `a`nchor tags make the browser reload the page each time, and then you see a completely new view

Comment: There's no link the OP want to go but prevented using preventDefault()

Answer (score 0):

The class is correctly added, you might want to change your CSS rules to:

```
li.red a {
    color:red;
}
```

to get the link text in red (assuming it's what you want).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) problem, Add a more specific rule to apply the style to anchor elements

```
.red a{
    color:red;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/C6NBy/)

Answer (score 0):

Class adding script is working you have to change your css

```
li.red a{color:red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The class is added. You should appy the css to the anchor tag.

Updated fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/wSt6Q/3/

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Handler for .ready() called.
        $("li").on("click", function () {       
            $(this).addClass("red");
        });
    });

.red a {
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent default action of your anchor tag.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $("li a").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //alert( $( this ).text() );
        $(this).addClass("red");
    });
});
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wSt6Q/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Another example:

html:

```
<ul>
   <li data-color="red">Red</li>
   <li data-color="blue">Blue</li>
   <li data-color="green">Green</li>
</ul>

<div>
   <label>Selected Color</label>
</div>
```

css:

```
.red{
   color: white;
   background: red;    
}

.blue{
   color: white;
   background: blue;
}

.green{
   color: white;
   background: green;
 }

div{
   text-align: center;
   width: 500px;
   height: 500px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

js:

```
$('li').on('click', function(){    
   var selectedColor = $(this).data('color');    
   $('div').removeClass();
   $('div').addClass(selectedColor);    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cfVw8/